# Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup. iOS

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to access all the folders of GoogleDrive ,in starting flow of authentication goes well but when i click on "Allow" ,i got all the folder and process ends up well, but now from couple of days after i go through same procedure, the fetch files method gets call but i am getting following error of exceeded daily limit

```
- (void)fetchFiles {
    GTLQueryDrive *query =
    [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
    query.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
    query.q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' IN parents AND trashed=false", @"root"];
    [self.service executeQuery:query
                      delegate:self
             didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}

- (void)displayResultWithTicket:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket
         finishedWithObject:(GTLDriveFileList *)response
                      error:(NSError *)error { //got error here }
```

**Error:**

```
Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "(Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.)" 
UserInfo={error=Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup., NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.), GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x60000044e8e0: {message:"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." data:[1] code:403}}
```

I have gone through this type of error but nothing seems to be right, anyone with help will be great

Comment: This error comes from making requests without authentication or in the case of files set to public without sending an API Key with your request.   Can you edit your question and show us your authentication code